# Gyroscope using Cocos2d-x

Tags: cocos2d-x, gyroscope

Does Cocos2d-x gives support for using gyroscope?  And if it isn't, then how can i use it?

Answer (score 2):

No. Cocos2d-x doesn't support gyroscope yet. Only accelerometer.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can see the class CCAccelerometer. and in the testcpp sample, there is a AccelerometerTest

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but you should enable it manually. You also can add a event listener that way :

```
Device::setAccelerometerEnabled(true);
Device::setAccelerometerInterval(1 / 30.0);

auto accelerationListener = EventListenerAcceleration::create(CC_CALLBACK_2(GameplayLayer::onAcceleration, this));
_eventDispatcher->addEventListenerWithSceneGraphPriority(accelerationListener, this);
```